# How to add a function in every class in vb.net and make it use local variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I have some similar classes, each of them has constant "Value"
I need a simple function in every class, called "Register", which will return the text `Value & ".REGISTER"`.

I tried to use `Inherits` in every class. It adds the function, but how do I access a local variable in this case?

Edit: It was said in answers that I should use MustOverride and Overrides. But in my case a function should be Shared, Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Check out [this MS tutorial on inheritance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307222/en-us).

Comment: Thanks! It seems I have to define MustOverride Property in base class

Answer (score 2):

Put the constant Value in the parent class that is inherited.

Alternatively, declare the property [MustOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb29zk8%28v=vs.90%29) in the parent class and use [Overrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k777kzw1%28v=vs.90%29) in the child classes.

Comment: It has to be different for every class that inherits function

Comment: Edited answer, you can use MustOverride and Overrides instead.

Comment: Thanks! This works! But in my application all function were shared, so I don't have to declare all the classes, just call the functions when needed. But MustOverride and Overrides seem to be incompatible with Shared. Is there any way to do the same thing with Shared Functions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to override shared properties like what you are trying to do.  There are a couple of workarounds that you might want to look into, though, explained in detail here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but maybe you can pass the VALUE in your Register function. what i mean is your Register function looks like

I am sorry but the solution is in c#. Its been a long time since I used vb. But I guess you will get an idea.

```
  public String Register(Integer VALUE)
    {
    ....
     Return Value + ".REGISTER";
    }
```

and pass the constant values in the parameters.

The other solution which i guess is not that efficient but might be what you need.

you can create the function Register in a static class. This way you don't need to inherit the class but you can simply call the function by the class name.

```
public static Class A
{
public String Register(Integer Value){...}
}
```

and call the function in other class as

```
Public class B{
public const int VALUE = 12;
String res = A.Register(A);
}
```